# JSP Tag for Registration Form

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

Here is the code for my custom tag(firstname.tag):

```
    Member m = (Member) request.getAttribute("member");
    if (m != null) {
        out.print(m.firstName);
    }
```

In my registration form I use it as value and the code goes like this:

```
<tr><td>First Name </td>
<td><input type="text" id="fname" value='<px2:firstname/>'></td>
</tr>
```

Am I using the tag properly? Thanks.

Comment: Does it work? What's the TLD? Do you really have a tag for every possible attribute?!

Comment: No TLD, not planning to use it. I do have tag for every attribute, haven't tried it yet, just want to confirm if I used the tag in a right way.

Comment: A tag for every possible attribute seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Except for the password. Do you think I should use TLD for this?

Comment: I don't even understand the point of having the tag, really. In any case, if I did anything, it'd be to have a tag that accepts the attribute name as an argument. That way you don't have to continually update your tag library. Or you could just do it using JSP EL, which seems significantly easier.

Comment: That is just for me to easily change something if I need to, will just update the tag if I need to change something in an attribute, I'll try your suggestion, I'll update you for the result, thanks

Comment: Having a separate tag to maintain for every attribute means any time there's a new attribute you have to create a new tag. This is a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: Don't use public fields, create a getter for the first name, and use `<c:out value="${member.firstName}"/>`: not tag to maintain, more readable, and properly escapes HTML special chars.